# Sending data from html using js and sending it on servlet getting there using gson

Tags: javascript, java, json

I'm trying to send a json object from js file to servlet and in servlet try to getting value but getting Null how i resolve plz suggest unable to get data from json object

JSON Object:

```
var Record ={  
   Username:document.getElementById("username").value,
   Name:document.getElementById("name").value,
   Contact:document.getElementById("phone").value,
   Email:document.getElementById("Email").value,
   DOB:document.getElementById("date").value,
   Team:team,
   Position:Position,
   PermanentAddress:document.getElementById("per_add").value,
   PermanentCountry:document.getElementById("country").value,
   permanentState:document.getElementById("state").value,
   permanentCity:document.getElementById("city").value,
   CurrentAddress:document.getElementById("CurrentAddress").value,
   CurrentCountry:document.getElementById("currentCountry").value,
   CurrentState:document.getElementById("currentState").value,
   CurrentCity:document.getElementById("currentCity").value
}
```

Sending data:

```
var PlayerData = JSON.stringify(Record);

$.post('/FootballLeagueController', PlayerData)
```

Inservlet:

```
 Gson gson=new Gson();
 FootballPlayerData playerData=new Gson().fromJson(request.getParameter("PlayerData")
  ,FootballPlayerData.class); //(comment)Note :-FootballPlayerData is my pojo class.
```

Answer (score 0):

request.getParameter(String) will give you the value of the post parameter "PlayerData", which does not exist in this case, because you are simply putting the JSON String inside the post body.
To have a parameter named "PlayerData", you can do the following:

```
$.post('/FootballLeagueController', {PlayerData: JSON.stringify(Record)})
```

This will send a parameter called "PlayerData" with the stringified JSON as value.

Please read and understand the [jquery.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) documentation for more information